# How to make Excel pivot table work in Google Sheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have an Excel spreadsheet which contains a pivot table. I want to convert this excel into Google sheet, so I uploaded it in Google sheet.

Everything gets converted successfully except the pivot table.

Is there a way the excel pivot can work in Google Sheets?

Please advise.

Comment: You will probably have to write all the functions to do the calculations yourself - pivot table is excel based...

Comment: Is it? Because I see that Google sheets also have pivot table functionality. Only task is how to convert Excel pivot table into Google sheet pivot table.

Comment: If it had the same functionality you would have got correct results.... As you say you did not get correct results, guess what that means... As long as you know what calculations you need to do then it will be easy...

Comment: recreat the pivot table in google sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that the excel pivot table actually got converted to Google sheet. The only reason why I felt it was not converted is that unlike Excel in Google sheets the filter does not get displayed on screen. The filter is working fine just not getting displayed on screen. That is not much of a worry. So I am good now.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to recreate it manually because not all Excel functions are backwards compatible with Google Sheets even if they are same or just similar